# How to make reflective glass material with emission shader

Tags: shader-nodes, emission

I got a set of nodes with a gradient, and the emission shader output. I would like those cubes to be more reflective almost like glass, and to be able to control their transparency if possible. How do I set up the nodes to the emission shader?

[image]

Comment: so you want to mix Emission with Glass nodes?

Comment: Hi :). Emission shader doesn't reflect light or receive shadows. What's a real world example of your desired result?

Comment: I wanted if possible something like this:

https://ibb.co/Y25DVcb

Answer (score 0):

Because *Emission* turns your mesh into a light, and it doesn't deal with normal surface responses, you can use an *Add Shader* here to add the emission effect to a *Glass BSDF*.

[image]

The rest is down to your lighting setup.

You can decrease *Emission* a little to get some translucency.

[image]